# Question on the CPA-security proof of the CTR-Mode

Tags: block-cipher, provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack

While reading [Katz & Lindell's textbook (2nd edition)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html) I found a proof for the CPA-Security of CTR-Mode. It can be found at the end of chapter 3.6.2 (page 93 and 94). I don't quite understand, why the proof is that complex, so I got two basic questions about it:

1. Why is the extra Scheme (cryptosystem) based on a true random function instead of a PRF necessary?
2. Why do we want to proof it with CPA-security for multiple messages? As far as I know, CPA-security for single messages implies CPA-security for multiple messages and vice versa. Therefore that just makes is unneccesary complex.

Why can't the proof be done simpler? The sketch of my idea would be:

1. Suppose A is an adversary against the CTR Kryptosystem based on a secure PRF function
2. A runs the CPA-Experiment with two messages $m_0, m_1$ and recieves $(IV,c)$ from the challenger
3. A can use its encryption Oracle for a polynomial amount of time $p(n)$ and gets, for simplicity, $n$ duples $(IV_i,c_i)$. That leads to 2 cases: 1. An overlap occurs. Because A does not only succeeds, if $IV = IV_i$ but also if $IV+x = IV_i+y$ (for some $x,y \geq 0$, because of the counting factor of CTR-Mode). So this happens in $2p(n)^2/2^n$ instead of $p(n)/2^n$ (birthday paradox, because of $IV+x = IV_i+y$). As probability to win in that case is 1, but the probability for this case is negligible: $2p(n)^2/2^n \in negl(n)$ 2. There is no overlap and A probability to win is $1/2$, because the PRF is secure.
4. Combining these two cases the probability of A to win is $1/2 + negl(n)$, which means, that CTR is CPA secure.

**Edit:**
Thank you for the answer! They helped me a lot in understanding the topic. But this led to another question related to this:

My professor proofed CPA-security for Encryption #1 based on PRF via a reduction proof using contradiction. The basic idea:

1. Basic assumption PRF is secure
2. Assume an adversary A against #1
3. Use A to build a distinguisher D to solve the the basic Assumption (D plays the CPA-game with A and therefore can break PRF)
4. Contradiction leads to proof if CPA-security

Because the proof in the book is based on the proof of the CPA-secure PRF-encryption, it should be possible to construct a proof, based on the the proof of the CPA-secure PRF-encryption using contradiction, right?

I give it a try:

This leads me to the following: A solution using contradiction would be more intuitiv (and I could understand it). So now therefore I give it a try:

1. Basic Assumption: PRF is secure
2. Assume an adversary A breaking the the encryption. A is able to use an encrpytion orakle (because we want to proof CPA-security). Let a have a non negligible success probability.
3. Using A we an build a distinguisher D breaking the PRF: D gets function not knowing weather it is a PRF or a true random function f. D simulates the CPA game with A using PRF or f. This leads to two cases:

3.1 D got a PRF. D is using the PRF-encryption scheme. A can break it with non negligible probability and D outputs what A ouputs.

3.2 D got a true random function. Now it gets funny: D firstly has to construct a new encrpytion scheme. For that he uses the old and just uses f instead of PRF. But now A can't win the game with more than a negligible probability: A can make p(n) many encryptions getting. Now the same argument as above can be used for overlapping (Because A does not only succeeds, if $IV = IV_i$ but also if $IV+x = IV_i+y$ (for some $x,y \geq 0$, because of the counting factor of CTR-Mode). So this happens in $2p(n)^2/2^n$ instead of $p(n)/2^n$ (birthday paradox, because of $IV+x = IV_i+y$). As probability to win in that case is 1, but the probability for this case is negligible: $2p(n)^2/2^n \in negl(n)$)

4. Therefore D can succeed with more than non negligible probability distinguishing PRF and f, which breaks PRF and therefore leads to a contradiction
5. Now only ING-CPA-security for single messages was shown, but because ING-CPA-security for single messages implies ING-CPA-security for multiple messages, we also showed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your statement "There is no overlap and A probability to win is $1/2$, because the PRF is secure." What does that mean? The only way to formalize that is to show that if adversary wins with probability greater than $1/2$ when there is no overlap, then you can break the PRF. That is essentially what the proof does. Note that it doesn't have to be by contradiction - it's also possible to show that when there is no overlap, then a reduction to distinguishing the PRF from random shows that the gap is negligible. That is the way the proof written in the book works.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the extra Scheme (cryptosystem) based on a true random function instead of a PRF necessary?

I don't have the book in front of me but every time you analyze the security of a PRF-based scheme, you always consider replacing the PRF with a truly random function as a *conceptual step* in the proof. A PRF is indistinguishable from a truly random function, so CTR mode based on a PRF is indistinguishable from CTR mode based on a truly random function. The latter is easier to analyze.

> Why do we want to proof it with CPA-security for multiple messages? As far as I know, CPA-security for single messages implies CPA-security for multiple messages and vice versa. Therefore that just makes is unneccesary complex.

This is true only for public-key encryption, not symmetric-key encryption. One-time pad is secure against single messages but obviously is not CPA secure.

> Why can't the proof be done simpler? The sketch of my idea would be ...

Your proof sketch is a sketch of the standard proof. It just requires more details to actually make it into a complete proof.

For example, you say that when there is "no overlap" [of the PRF inputs], the "probability to win is 1/2, because the PRF is secure." This is not a "direct" consequence of the PRF security definition. The only way to prove it formally is to argue that (1) the PRF is indistinguishable from a truly random function (this is all that the PRF security definition says); (2) in CTR mode with a truly random function, when there are no repeats among the PRF-inputs, all ciphertext blocks are truly uniformly random (using the fact that they are XOR of plaintext with independent outputs of the random function); (3) when the ciphertext blocks are uniformly random, the adversary's success probability is exactly 1/2. There is really no more direct way to argue this formally.

Comment: I see what you want to tell me but: 1. I can't find the contradiction in the reduction proof, therefore I don't understand the proof at all (also can't find other similarities to the PRF-based reduction proofs) 2. OTP isn't CPA-secure anyway, because OTP is deterministic, and I never stated that ING-EAV-Single implies ING-CPA-security. I stated that ING-CPA-Single implies ING-CPA-Mult security and vice versa

Comment: How do you show that deterministic encryption is not CPA secure? By considering an attack where the adversary **asks to see 2 ciphertexts.** How are you going to argue that there's a problem, if the attacker sees just one OTP ciphertext? That ciphertext will be truly uniform.